# Any idea on how to get this id from the conversation between attendee and bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

**Context:**

BotFramework (C# SDK) + Messenger channel, bot handles two types of users: attendees (Messenger users) and organizers (who are Facebook Page's admins).

**Use case:**

When an attendee requests a human support (using an option in my bot's menu), the organizer will receive a message.

In that message, I would like to add a button that will do the following once clicked by the organizer:

1. stop the automatic replies from the bot to that user
2. redirect the organizer to Facebook's Page inbox, with the conversation (between the attendee and the bot) selected

**What I have done:**

- I successfully did the part to stop the automatic replies
- I got stuck on how to redirect the organizer to the right conversation in FB Page's inbox

**Technically:**

When I'm looking in Facebook Page, the link that seems to be the one that I should generate for my action is like the following: `https://www.facebook.com/mypage-mypageId/inbox/?selected_item_id=someId`

My problem is that I can't find this value for `selected_item_id` from my bot's conversation.

Comment: Where in your code are you sending the message to the agent?  What exactly is the "selected_item_id"?  You ask: "how to get select_item_id" from initial conversation" but I have no context to understand what selected_item_id actually is.  Please explain.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to get a link to the facebook page inbox (with the right thread) thanks to Facebook Graph API.

`/me/conversations` must be called to get the conversations of the Page (so you have to give an access_token of the page to the API call).

Then in those results, you have to make a match with the conversation of the attendee. To do this, you can use the **property `id` of the Activity** in your bot (Activity.Id, not Activity.Conversation.Id!) as this value is common between your bot and facebook graph results (just need to add "m_" to match): you can find it in one `message.id` on your Graph API results (careful: not conversation.id)

Then you can get the `link` value of the Graph API result for this conversation that you found: `"link": "\/myBotName\/manager\/messages\/?threadid=10154736814928655&folder=inbox"` in my test

Here is a sample of a Dialog that will search for the link for a specific message id:

```
[Serializable]
public class FacebookGetLinkTestDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var jsonString = "";
        var link = "";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/conversations?access_token=yourAccessTokenHere").ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var conversationList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationsRootObject>(jsonString);
                link = conversationList.data.Single(c => c.messages.data.Any(d => d.id.Equals("m_" + "yourActivityIdHere"))).link;
            }
        }
        await context.PostAsync($"{link}");
    }
}

public class ConversationsRootObject
{
    public List<Conversation> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}

public class Conversation
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string snippet { get; set; }
    public string updated_time { get; set; }
    public int message_count { get; set; }
    public int unread_count { get; set; }
    public Participants participants { get; set; }
    public FormerParticipants former_participants { get; set; }
    public Senders senders { get; set; }
    public Messages messages { get; set; }
    public bool can_reply { get; set; }
    public bool is_subscribed { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}

public class Participant
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Participants
{
    public List<Participant> data { get; set; }
}

public class FormerParticipants
{
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
}

public class Senders
{
    public List<Participant> data { get; set; }
}

public class Messages
{
    public List<FbMessage> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}

public class FbMessage
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should i use some conversion between ids ? Because they aren't the same. The id i receive from graph looks like this :  `t_mid.someNumber:9b0f112e52` 
The id from acitivity (activity.Id) : `mid.$cAAP8wkY2a91i10BEQ1cpfr5erOvg`

Comment: You are not looking in the right field in Graph API. The value you provide is an `id` of a Graph `conversation`(top level), here the link we are trying to do is with the `id` of a `message` (lower level)

Comment: BTW : This works also with context.Activity.Id. v3.8

Comment: Where do you find the activity (or activity.id) of the bot?   I am not using the BotFramework

Comment: /me/conversations is now deprecated and is uncallable by applications using v2.5+ facebook API.

Comment: You can list the conversations of a Facebook page using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/ , then with the `id` fields of the conversation you can query the messages