# How to get facebook page inbox link to the particular users conversation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have built a bot using facebook messenger webhook. Bot is working fine, now I have requirement to give a direct inbox link to conversation between user and bot, which looks something like this www.facebook.com//inbox/?selected_item_id=.

Now the problem I am facing is how do I get selected_item_id. 
Through webhook I got sender_id and a message_id, is there any way through which I can get this selected item id using users_id or message_id?

I have gone through facebook graph but it didn't help. Facebook webhook does not provide conversation_id as parameter, even if I get conversation id enough, rest I can handle. Please let me know if there is any way I can get through this.

Comment: Same here, looking for a solution, did you find anything @akhil

Comment: This link might help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501474/any-idea-on-how-to-get-this-id-from-the-conversation-between-attendee-and-bot][1]